# Multiple browser tabs using Spring 3.2

Tags: spring, session, browser, tabs

Opening multiple tabs in my web application causes it to misbehave due to session corruption. How can I support multiple browser tabs using spring 3.2 and preferably without adding even more frameworks?

Comment: What do you mean by "session corruption"? Any Servlet container is capable of handling multiple requests for the same session, and Spring does not break this in any way. No matter what you do, though, each tab will (in most cases) share the same session. Without knowing anything about your application, I'd say you need to  either avoid keeping tab-specific state in the session, or give each tab some sort of id and append-prepend that id to any session attributes you set.

Comment: The problem is if the user opens multiple tabs and edits two objects in each one of them, they either get mixed up or don't submit at all because the attributes get mixed. That's what I meant by "session corruption". How would I go about appending a window id to the attributes?

Comment: Are they the same logical object (eg Account #1356 being edited by both tabs)? If so, your problem isn't multiple tabs, it's multiple users of any kind. If it's multiple tabs editing the same *kind* of document (eg tab 1 editing Account #1, tab 2 editing Account #2) and running into conflicts with session variable names, then you could generate some ID to identify each tab. Just do it client-side (Math.random() or something) and pass it along.

Comment: Or better yet, don't keep that state in the session.

Comment: I was able to solve this by not keeping my objects in the session. However, I face a new problem. By keeping the objects in the model attributes, everything that isn't on the .jsp is null on the POST method. This is bypassed by storing everything in hidden forms on the .jsp, but isn't very elegant or safe. Spring 3.1 introduced the class RedirectAttributes, which extends Models and allows attributes to be stored and "survive" one redirect, which means everything is there when you press the submit button.(cont)

Comment: (cont.)However, when switching my function argument from Model to RedirectAttributes I just get a 400 error.

Comment: Without any code, it's hard to know exactly what your problem is. This tutorial on Spring MVC might help: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-handling-forms/